# How to make Postfix recive mails on main domain

Tags: postfix-mta, slackware

How can I make in postfix recive mail on my domain?
ex. here I wont revice mail: neko@domain.com not like this: neko@mail.domain.com
Here is how I put in main.cf, but dosn't work

```
mydomain = domain.com
myorigin = $mydomain
```

Any solution?

Comment: Add the domain to your mydestination list.

Answer (score 0):

take a closer look at mydestination in main.cf:
http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination

here is an example, main.cf:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no

myhostname = mail.domain.com
inet_protocols = ipv4
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain
virtual_mailbox_domains = domain.com
```